# Application not show Android Pie

Tags: android

I have Created an application in android, and hosted in play store
the application works fine in all version except android 9. when i search my application
in android pie version using playstore, it is not showing my application,
I had set the sdk version to 28, but it is not showing my application.
I don't know what is the problem. Please help to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.name"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 42
    versionName "5.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
  }
   dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
// compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
//  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
//  compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
// compile 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.7'
//compile 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.8'
implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.11.0'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:1
// 1.4.2'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.danielemaddaluno.androidupdatechecker:library:1.0.2'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0'
//  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.kassisdion:ViewPagerWithIndicator:v1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation files('libs/PGSDK_V2.0.jar')
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you add your build.gradle file

Comment: i updated my query.please check it.

Comment: remove buildToolsVersion '28.0.2' and try

Comment: did you add any restrictions in android manifest ? .Try searching in playstore with your applicationId "com.sample.name"

Comment: have you try to use android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in your manifest?